# How to write correct loops?

Tags: programming-practices, loops

Most of time while writing loops I usually write wrong boundary conditions(eg: wrong outcome) or my assumptions about loop terminations are wrong(eg: infinitely running loop). Although I got my assumptions correct after some trial and error but I got too frustrated because of the lack of correct computing model in my head.

```
/**
 * Inserts the given value in proper position in the sorted subarray i.e. 
 * array[0...rightIndex] is the sorted subarray, on inserting a new value 
 * our new sorted subarray becomes array[0...rightIndex+1].
 * @param array The whole array whose initial elements [0...rightIndex] are 
 * sorted.
 * @param rightIndex The index till which sub array is sorted.
 * @param value The value to be inserted into sorted sub array.
 */
function insert(array, rightIndex, value) {
    for(var j = rightIndex; j >= 0 && array[j] > value; j--) {
        array[j + 1] = array[j];
    }   
    array[j + 1] = value; 
};
```

The mistakes that I did initially were:

1. Instead of j >= 0 I kept it j > 0.
2. Got confused whether array[j+1] = value or array[j] = value.

What are tools/mental models to avoid such mistakes?

Comment: Under what circumstances do you believe that `j >= 0` is a mistake?     I would be more wary of the fact that you are accessing `array[j]` and `array[j + 1]` without first checking that `array.length > (j + 1)`.

Comment: @BenCottrell corrected.

Comment: @ThomasJunk yes the question is general and hence the problem too. I think there are people who makes the same mistakes as I do and there are others too who are able to get away with these silly mistakes. Yes, they are silly because they derail you from your actual problem and hence eat up a lot of time. If you know the solution then please help us out, otherwise your comment is no good than Donal Trump.

Comment: It is not clear to me what to code does. Is the array supposed to be sorted beforehand? What is the purpose of the rightIndex parameter?

Comment: @JacquesB: It is an insertion sort.

Comment: Just don't try to reinvent solved problems (such as data structures) and you'll be fine.

Comment: akin to what @LightnessRacesinOrbit said, you are likely solving problems that have already been solved. Generally speaking any looping you need to do over a data structure already exists in some core module or class (on the `Array.prototype` in the example of JS). This prevents you from encountering edge conditions since something like `map` works on all arrays.  You can solve the above using slice and concat to avoid looping all together: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWovdg?editors=0012 The most correct way to write a loop is to not write one at all.

Comment: Actually, go ahead and solve solved problems.  It's called practice.  Just don't bother publishing them.  That is, unless you find a way to improve the solutions.  That said, reinventing the wheel involves more than the wheel.  It involves a whole wheel quality control system and customer support.  Still, custom rims are nice.

Comment: @CandiedOrange can't agree with you a bit. I can't read algorithms like a story I need to get my hands dirty to get it into my head. Also, my question is not regarding algorithm but some other technical detail which might be helpful in many ways.

Comment: There seems to be a disconnect here regarding the *purpose* of this exercise. To clarify: this sort of exercise is useful for improving one's understanding, knowledge, and experience; however, for the wide majority of applications, you should never roll your own implementation of a well-known algorithm, simply because existing standard libraries have been tried and tested in far more cases than one themselves might ever expect to put their code through, and are generally more robust and reliable.

Comment: I fear we're headed in the wrong direction here.  Giving CodeYogi crap because his example is part of a well known algorithm is rather baseless.  He never claimed he'd invented something new.  He's asking how to avoid some very common boundary errors when writing a loop.  Libraries have come a long way but I still see a future for people who know how to write loops.

Comment: @CodeYogi you've asked an important and well received question.  I'd like to understand what issues you feel are still outstanding.

Comment: @Jed Schneider: Re "...any looping you need to do over a data structure already exists...".  This is utter nonsense.  Now it's true that some loopings may already be implemented (e.g. you can call a sort routine instead of writing your own), but suppose you are developing code for some new algorithm/function?

Comment: @jamesqf next you two will be arguing about whether anyone should write anything in assembly nowadays.  The only excuse I need to write at whatever level of abstraction I feel like is, "because I can".  But yeah, make choices that make life easy.

Comment: In general, when dealing with loops and indexes you should learn that [indices point between elements](https://blog.nelhage.com/2015/08/indices-point-between-elements/) and familiarize yourself with [half-open intervals](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-Python-ranges-half-open-exclusive-instead-of-closed-inclusive/answer/Anders-Kaseorg) (actually, they are two sides of the same concepts). Once you get these facts, much of the loops/indexes head-scratching disappears completely.

Comment: @MatteoItalia very good points and links.  Indices have a long tradition of pointing between elements.  You'll find examples on any ruler or tape measure.

Comment: "Do TDD" doesn't mean the same thing as "test your code".  The whole point about TDD is that you start by thinking about what conditions your code needs to cater for.  You can throw in cases about whether your loop includes 0, or includes the last element of an array, or whatever.  Having the cases before you have the code will help you think about making sure the code is right.  Actually running the test is really just a double-check.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38520/discussion-on-question-by-codeyogi-how-to-write-correct-loops).

Comment: Mental models: In all your looping algorithms, stop passing around and/or thinking about `rightIndex`, instead, think (and pass) in terms of `size` of the array.

Comment: [Also posted on Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56058/how-to-use-the-concept-of-loop-invariant-to-reduce-errors-in-loops). [Please don't do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). I think it makes sense to ask about loop invariants both to programmers and to computer scientists — but your question must be tailored to each site: computer scientists don't care about competitive programming, for instance.

Comment: @CodeYogi Tone it down and [be nice](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), please.

Comment: @Newtopian which one? which one gives me new insight so that from now on I cannot write wrong loops, please do let me know which one does so and I will accept that.

Comment: @CodeYogi : CandiedOrange seems to have reached a consensus amongst readers of the question.  That said, it's your question, it's entirely up to you, if you feel he did not answer it then leave it open though if you do feel this way I'd be curious to know why ?  What's missing ?  Perhaps we could build a wiki response combining the best aspects of all questions, comments and chat.  It is a good question, as such deserves a good answer.

Comment: @Newtopian as I said do you feel that you can now write the loops correctly based on that answer, if yes then justify because I can't I would still feel terrible because test case would show me I am wrong but would never tell me why, in terms of new insight I find http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/316056/198298 an interesting one because it gives you new insight but that is relative comparison and if I ever have to accept an answer then that is the best candidate Talking about most up votes I doubt how much must have read the whole answer.

Comment: @CodeYogi I dont think there exist an absolute truth about writing loops that will appy to all languages all the time.  There are common gotcha's and pitfalls (such as off by one) and most languages will stick to the common conventions but there will always be corner cases and obscure implementations for which these rules will not apply.  Since it is clearly impossible to get an absolute answer, the next best thing is to compose a new answer (or augment an existing one) with the best parts of each and let it evolve as the reference to put things to watch out for when writing loops.

Comment: @Newtopian go for it then.

Answer (score 214):

### Test

No, seriously, test.

I've been coding for over 20 years and I still don't trust myself to write a loop correctly the first time.  I write and run tests that prove it works before I suspect it works. Test each side of every boundary condition. For example a `rightIndex` of 0 should do what? How about -1?

### Keep it simple

If others can't see what it does at a glance you're making it too hard.  Please feel free to ignore performance if it means you can write something easy to understand.  Only make it faster in the unlikely event that you really need to. And even then only once you're absolutely sure you know exactly what is slowing you down. If you can achieve an actual [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) improvement this activity may not be pointless, but even then, make your code as readable as possible.

### Off by one

Know the difference between counting your fingers and counting the spaces between your fingers.  Sometimes the spaces are what is actually important.  Don't let your fingers distract you. Know whether your thumb is a finger. Know whether the gap between your pinky and thumb counts as a space.

### Comments

Before you get lost in the code try to say what you mean in English.  State your expectations clearly.  Don't explain how the code works. Explain why you're having it do what it does. Keep implementation details out of it. It should be possible to refactor the code without needing to change the comment.

The best comment is a good name.

If you can say everything you need to say with a good name, DON'T say it again with a comment.

### Abstractions

Objects, functions, arrays, and variables are all abstractions that are only as good as the names they are given. Give them names that ensure when people look inside them they won't be surprised by what they find.

### Short names

Use short names for short lived things. `i` is a fine name for an index in a nice tight loop in a small scope that makes it's meaning obvious.  If `i` lives long enough to get spread out over line after line with other ideas and names that can be confused with `i` then it's time to give `i` a nice long explanatory name.

### Long names

Never shorten a name simply due to line length considerations.  Find another way to lay out your code.

### Whitespace

Defects love to hide in unreadable code.  If your language lets you choose your indentation style at least be consistent.  Don't make your code look like a stream of word wrapped noise.  Code should look like it's marching in formation.

### Loop constructs

Learn and review the loop structures in your language.  [Watching a debugger highlight a `for(;;)` loop](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4303/1401)  can be very instructive.  Learn all the forms:  `while`, `do while`, `while(true)`, `for each`. Use the simplest one you can get away with.  Look up [priming the pump](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/316209/131624).  Learn what `break` and `continue` do if you have them.  Know the difference between `c++` and `++c`.  Don't be afraid to return early as long as you always close everything that needs closing. [Finally blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Exception_support_in_programming_languages) or preferably something that marks it for automatic closing when you open it: [Using statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) / [Try with Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

### Loop alternatives

Let something else do the looping if you can. It's easier on the eyes and already debugged. These come in many forms: collections or streams that allow `map()`, `reduce()`, `foreach()`, and other such methods that apply a lambda. Look for specialty functions like `Arrays.fill()`. There is also recursion but only expect that to make things easy in special cases. Generally don't use recursion until you see what the alternative would look like. If someone tells you tail recursion will magically keep you from blowing the stack then first check if your language optimizes tail recursion. Not all of them do.

### Oh, and test.

Test, test, test.

Did I mention testing?

There was one more thing.  Can't remember.  Started with a T...

Comment: Good answer, but maybe you should mention testing. How does one deal with infinite loop in unit test ? Doesn't such loop 'break' the tests ???

Comment: @GameAlchemist That's the pizza test.  If my code doesn't stop running in the time it takes me to make a pizza I start to suspect something is wrong.  Sure it's no cure for Alan Turing's halting problem but at least I get a pizza outta the deal.

Comment: -one not enough TEST! (but seriously, +1 for putting *almost* as much stress on testing as should be put).

Comment: I would also add use `forEach` whenever possible if supported. 9/10 times you don't actually care what order your collection is iterated in, and a `forEach` avoids all the off-by-one and infinte loop errors.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg well I already listed for each. And since I can write my own buggy iterators I can still send for each into an infinite loop. But you're right, sometimes I don't care about the order of iteration.  Which makes me think I should also list map reduce.

Comment: @CandiedOrange so, you say TDD is a solution for each and everything therefore no need to program verification and loop invariant those things are stupid. Dude, I know TDD well and we can have a long discussion over that but **TDD can't guarantee that you thinking right, it can verify that your solution is correct but can't give you the solution itself**.

Comment: @CodeYogi - actually, it can get *very* close.  Start with a test that operates on a single value.   Implement the code without a loop.  Then write a test that operates on two values.  Implement the loop.  It is *very* unlikely you'll get a boundary condition wrong on the loop if you do it like this, because in almost all circumstances either one or the other of these two tests will fail if you make such a mistake.

Comment: @CodeYogi - see also: https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/05/27/TheTransformationPriorityPremise.html - following these rules will force you to write tests that make the loop work.

Comment: @CodeYogi Dude all due credit to TDD but Testing >> TDD.  Outputting a value can be testing, getting a second set of eyes on your code is testing (you can formalize this as a code review but I often just grab someone for a 5 minute conversation).  A test is any chance you give an expression of your intent to fail.  Hell you can test your code by talking through an idea with your mom .  I've found bugs in my code when staring at the tile in the shower. TDD is an effective formalized discipline that you don't find in every shop.  I've never once coded anywhere where people didn't test.

Comment: @CodeYogi:where in this answer do you actually read "TDD"? Did you mix up testing with TDD? Where in this answer do you read "test (or TDD) is the one and only solution to the problem you were asking"?

Comment: @CodeYogi: no need to insult me. I was neither the one who wrote the answer, nor the one who obviously misinterpreted this answer (you will find plenty of posts here on PSE explaining you the differences between testing and TDD). My opinion: this answer is good advice to your question when you read it carefully, completely, and understand what it means.

Comment: I was coding and testing years and years before I'd ever heard of TDD.  It's only now that I realize the correlation of those years to the years spent coding while wearing no pants.

Comment: That thing about fingers and spaces and thumbs is really insightful. Did that come from a book (in which case, which one?), or did you make it up (in which case, nice one!). Explaining off-by-one to novices is hard, it'd be good to have a "standard" metaphor.

Comment: @DocBrown show me the code! if I needed opinions then I have link to google search and hundreds of blog links about TDD and testing.

Comment: @IainGalloway Thanks!  I've spent some time as a c++ and discrete mathematics tutor (among others).  After a while I got tired of drawing fence posts and realized I could teach "off by one" by holding up my hand and asking people, "How many spaces between my fingers am I holding up".  It can get you a variety of numbers and the strangest looks. :)

Comment: I'm a big fan of testing and test-driven development, but relying solely on TDD to get your loops bounds correct could lead to cargo cultish hacking until it works instead of designing a principled implementation.  Thus I don't think this answer addresses the question, which is how to think about loops, as well as some of the other answers.

Comment: @corsika S.O. asks me to pick a name while I'm eating candied orange slices and the rest is history. While I'll take credit for the finger idea, I have to give credit for the pizza test to eggdrop. It's a simple role reversal of this informative make message: [This will take a while. Go make a pizza or something.](http://cvs.eggheads.org/viewvc/eggdrop1.9/src/Makefile?view=co)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I'm a big fan of the console, debug print statements, logging, assertions, invariants, design by contract, strongly typed languages, design, requirements, customer feedback, domain experts, taking a break before rereading your code and many other **tests** that predate the wonderful red green refactor cycle. I'm not driven by tests. I'm obsessed with tests. I'm driven to find a design that pairs my love of features with my hatred of code. You are absolutely right, hammering randomly on code to make a test pass is not Software Engineering.  It's a really slow genetic algorithm.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I want but couldn't accept your answer without any code example. Think about someone who gets caught in the same situation, what advice he will get from your answer that he can't get from anywhere else?

Comment: @CandiedOrange I feel the off by one analogy is excellent, yet might be hard to connect to coding for those who need this explanation the most; maybe you could make this link a little more explicit.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy TDD wasn't even mentioned in the answer. And more importantly, this doesn't really MEAN anything. "Relying solely on X without thinking won't magically solve all your problems" is true for all Xs. No one here (and especially not this answer) has claimed that doing any kind of testing will magically turn you into an omniscient being incapable of writing bugs. It's about how you can VERIFY if your implementation has bugs or not, and barring formal mathematical proofs, testing is THE only way of doing that, be they automatic, manual, first- och after the fact.

Comment: I think your answer is great but could you please elaborate what you mean by **Lookup priming the pump**? As a non native english speaker I cannot comprehend the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: @ooxi Good question.  I liked it so much [I stole it](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/316209/131624)

Comment: Pseudo-code always helps :)

Comment: A unit test runner will often have a timeout to prevent infinite loops. And for many functions, if they deliver the correct result after two minutes they are as good as broken. Unit tests should be able to give you a result like “test 1 to 138 ran successfully except test 19 and 107, 139 never finished, 140 to 380 were never started. “

Answer (score 74):

When programming it is useful to think of:

- pre-conditions
- post-conditions
- [variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_variant)
- and invariants (of [loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant) or [types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant))

and when exploring uncharted territory (such as juggling with indices) it can be very, *very*, useful to not just think about those but actually make them explicit in the code with **assertions**.

Let's take your original code:

```
/**
 * Inserts the given value in proper position in the sorted subarray i.e. 
 * array[0...rightIndex] is the sorted subarray, on inserting a new value 
 * our new sorted subarray becomes array[0...rightIndex+1].
 * @param array The whole array whose initial elements [0...rightIndex] are 
 * sorted.
 * @param rightIndex The index till which sub array is sorted.
 * @param value The value to be inserted into sorted sub array.
 */
function insert(array, rightIndex, value) {
    for(var j = rightIndex; j >= 0 && array[j] > value; j--) {
        array[j + 1] = array[j];
    }   
    array[j + 1] = value; 
};
```

And check what we have:

- pre-condition: `array[0..rightIndex]` is sorted
- post-condition: `array[0..rightIndex+1]` is sorted
- invariant: `0 <= j <= rightIndex` but it seems redundant a bit; or as @Jules noted in the comments, at the end of a "round", `for n in [j, rightIndex+1] => array[j] > value`.
- invariant: at the end of a "round", `array[0..rightIndex+1]` is sorted

So you can first write a `is_sorted` function as well as a `min` function working on an array slice, and then assert away:

```
function insert(array, rightIndex, value) {
    assert(is_sorted(array[0..rightIndex]));

    for(var j = rightIndex; j >= 0 && array[j] > value; j--) {
        array[j + 1] = array[j];

        assert(min(array[j..rightIndex+1]) > value);
        assert(is_sorted(array[0..rightIndex+1]));
    }   
    array[j + 1] = value; 

    assert(is_sorted(array[0..rightIndex+1]));
};
```

There is also the fact that your loop condition is a bit complicated; you might want to make it easier on yourself by splitting things up:

```
function insert(array, rightIndex, value) {
    assert(is_sorted(array[0..rightIndex]));

    for (var j = rightIndex; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (array[j] <= value) { break; }

        array[j + 1] = array[j];

        assert(min(array[j..rightIndex+1]) > value);
        assert(is_sorted(array[0..rightIndex+1]));
    }   
    array[j + 1] = value; 

    assert(is_sorted(array[0..rightIndex+1]));
};
```

Now, the loop is straightforward (`j` goes from `rightIndex` to `0`).

Finally, now this needs to be tested:

- think of boundary conditions (`rightIndex == 0`, `rightIndex == array.size - 2`)
- think of `value` being smaller than `array[0]` or larger than `array[rightIndex]`
- think of `value` being equal to `array[0]`, `array[rightIndex]` or some middle index

Also, do not underestimate *fuzzing*. You have assertions in place to catch mistakes, so generate a random array and sort it using your method. If an assertion fires, you found a bug and can extend your test suite.

Comment: Ah, finally the answer I was looking for, at-least you understand my question. So, finally we can have some discussion. How, would you go for to check `array[j+1] = value or array[j]=value`?

Comment: @CodeYogi: With... tests. The thing is, it can be impractical to express *everything* in assertions: if the assertion merely repeats the code, then it does not bring anything *new* (repetition does not help with quality). This is why here I did not assert in the loop that `0 <= j <= rightIndex` or `array[j] <= value`, it would just repeat the code. On the other hand, `is_sorted` brings a new guarantee, thus it's valuable. Afterwards, that's what tests are for. If you call `insert([0, 1, 2], 2, 3)` to your function and the output isn't `[0, 1, 2, 3]` then you've found a bug.

Comment: @psmears: Good point, I informally rewrote the loop header to make it obvious that it terminated but some terminology is always helpful.

Comment: You missed a relevant and useful loop invariant: `forall n . j <= n < rightIndex => array[n] > value`, which forces you to check for the termination point correctly.

Comment: @Jules: Indeed!

Comment: @MatthieuM. don't discount the value of an assertion simply because it duplicates the code.  Infact, those can be very valuable assertions to have if you decide to rewrite the code.  Testing has every right to be duplicative.    Rather consider if the assertion it is so coupled to a single code implementation that any rewrite would invalidate the assertion.  That's when you're wasting your time.  Nice answer by the way.

Comment: @CodeYogi glad you found something you liked.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: By duplicating the code I mean literally `array[j+1] = array[j]; assert(array[j+1] == array[j]);`. In this case, the value seems very very low (it's a copy/paste). If you duplicate the meaning but expressed in another fashion, then it becomes more valuable.

Comment: Hoare's rules: helping to write correct loops since 1969. "Still, even though these techniques have been known for more than a decade, most porgrammers have never heard of them".

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree that it has very low value.  But I don't think of it as being caused by it being a copy/paste.  Say I wanted to refactor `insert()` so that it worked by copying from an old array to new array.  That can be done without breaking your other `assert`'s.  But not this last one.  Just shows how well your other `assert`'s were designed.

Comment: Someone *had* to go Hoare logic on this question! :)

Comment: Infact I like the condition within the loop, it helps you to translate whatever condition is in your mind directly. For example `move j backward until its greater than zero or less than right hand size values` which translates fine to `j >= 0 && array[j] > value`, wdyt?

Answer (score 28):

### Use unit testing/TDD

If you really need to access sequences through a `for` loop, you can avoid the mistakes through **unit testing**, and especially **test driven development**.

Imagine you need to implement a method which takes the values which are superior to zero, in reverse order. What test cases could you think of?

1. A sequence contains one value which is superior to zero.

   Actual: `[5]`. Expected: `[5]`.

   The most straightforward implementation which satisfies the requirements consists of simply returning the source sequence to the caller.
2. A sequence contains two values, both superior to zero.

   Actual: `[5, 7]`. Expected: `[7, 5]`.

   Now, you cannot just return the sequence, but you should reverse it. Would you use a `for (;;)` loop, another language construct or a library method doesn't matter.
3. A sequence contains three values, one being zero.

   Actual: `[5, 0, 7]`. Expected: `[7, 5]`.

   Now you should change the code to filter the values. Again, this could be expressed through an `if` statement or a call to your favorite framework method.
4. Depending on your algorithm (since this is white-box testing, the implementation matters), you may need to handle specifically the empty sequence `[] → []` case, or maybe not. Or you may ensure that the edge case where all values are negative `[-4, 0, -5, 0] → []` is handled correctly, or even that boundary negative values are: `[6, 4, -1] → [4, 6]; [-1, 6, 4] → [4, 6]`. In many cases, however, you'll only have the three tests described above: any additional test won't make you change your code, and so would be irrelevant.

### Work at higher abstraction level

However, in many cases, you can avoid most of those errors by working at a higher abstraction level, using existent libraries/frameworks. Those libraries/frameworks make it possible to revert, sort, split and join the sequences, to insert or remove values in arrays or doubly-linked lists, etc.

Usually, `foreach` can be used instead of `for`, making boundary conditions checking irrelevant: the language does it for you. Some languages, such as Python, don't even have the `for (;;)` construct, but only `for ... in ...`.

In C#, LINQ is particularly convenient when working with sequences.

```cs
var result = source.Skip(5).TakeWhile(c => c > 0);
```

is much more readable and less error prone compared to its `for` variant:

```cs
for (int i = 5; i < source.Length; i++)
{
    var value = source[i];
    if (value <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    yield return value;
}
```

Comment: what is I am bound to use a particular language? for example in an interview?

Comment: Unit tests are universal.

Comment: @CodeYogi: don't you think the interviewer would be delighted to learn that you know TDD? So why wouldn't you show that during an interview?

Comment: Yes, I do TDD but sometimes I just get into the trap of hit and try and finally I am able to get to the correct solution but with the cost of time and negative feedback to the interviewer. Don't you think generic proof/thought on loop correctness would be a good heuristic while doing TDD?

Comment: Well, from your original question, I have an impression that the choice is on one hand using TDD and getting the correct solution, and on the other hand skipping the test part and getting the boundary conditions wrong.

Comment: Thank you for being the one to mention the elephant in the room: **not using loops *at all***. *Why* people still code like its 1985 (and I'm being generous) is beyond me. BOCTAOE.

Comment: @JaredSmith Everybody got used to the elephant. Only the newcomers think it's something weird, and they get used to it quickly as well. COBOL is still alive :P

Comment: @JaredSmith Once the computer actually executes that code, how much do you want to bet there is no jump instruction in there? By using LINQ you are *abstracting away* the loop, but it's still there. I've explained this to coworkers who failed to learn about the hard work of [Shlemiel the painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html). Failing to understand where loops occur, even if they are abstracted away in the code and the code is significantly more readable as a result, almost invariably leads to performance issues that one will be at a loss to explain, let alone fix.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: when you use LINQ, the *loop* is there, but [a `for(;;)` construct wouldn't be very descriptive of this loop](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/178225/6605). An important aspect is that LINQ (as well as list comprehensions in Python and similar elements in other languages) makes boundary conditions mostly irrelevant, at least within the scope of the original question. However, I can't agree more about the need to understand what happens under the hood when using LINQ, especially when it comes to lazy evaluation.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I wasn't necessarily talking about LINQ and I kinda fail to see your point. `forEach`, `map`, `LazyIterator`, etc. are provided by the language's compiler or runtime environment and are arguably *less* likely to be walking back to the paint bucket on each iteration. That, readability, and off-by-one errors are the two reasons those features were added to modern languages.

Comment: Map -> Reduce FTW +1

Answer (score 16):

I agree with other people who say test your code.  However, it's also nice to get it right in the first place.  I have a tendency to get boundary conditions wrong in many cases, so I've developed mental tricks to prevent such problems.

With a 0-indexed array, your normal conditions are going to be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

or

```
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Those patterns should become second nature, your shouldn't have to think about those at all.

But not everything follows that exact pattern.  So if you're not sure if you wrote it right, here's your next step:

Plug in values and evaluate the code in your own brain.  Make it as simple to think about as you possible can.  What happens if the relevant values are 0s?  What happens if they are 1s?

```
for(var j = rightIndex; j >= 0 && array[j] > value; j--) {
    array[j + 1] = array[j];
}   
array[j + 1] = value;
```

In your example, you're not sure if it should be [j] = value or [j+1] = value.  Time to start evaluating it manually:

What happens if you have an array length 0?  The answer becomes obvious: rightIndex must be (length - 1) == -1, so j starts at -1, so to insert at index 0, you need to add 1.

So we've proved the final condition correct, but not the inside of the loop.

What happens if you have an array with 1 element, 10, and we try to insert a 5?  With a single element, rightIndex should start at 0.  So the first time through the loop, j = 0, so "0 >= 0 && 10 > 5".  Since we want to insert the 5 at index 0, the 10 should get moved to index 1, so array[1] = array[0].  Since this happens when j is 0, array[j + 1] = array[j + 0].

If you try to imagine some large array and what happens inserting into some arbitrary location, your brain will probably get overwhelmed.  But if you stick to simple 0/1/2 size examples, it should be easy to do a quick mental run through and see where your boundary conditions break down.

Imagine you never heard of the fence post problem before and I tell you I have 100 fence posts in a straight line, how many segments between them.  If you try to imagine 100 fence posts in your head, you're just going to get overwhelmed.  So what's the fewest fence posts to make a valid fence?  You need 2 to make a fence, so imagine 2 posts, and the mental image of a single segment between the posts makes it very clear.  You don't have to sit there counting posts and segments because your made the problem into something intuitively obvious to your brain.

Once you think it's correct, it's then good to run it through a test and make sure the computer does what you think it should, but at that point it should just be a formality.

Comment: I really like `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)`.  Once I got into that habit, I stopped using `<=` nearly as often, and felt that loops got simpler.  But `for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)` seems overly complicated, compared to: `for (int i=length; i--; )` (which would probably be even more sensible to write as a `while` loop unless I was trying to make `i` have a smaller scope/life).  Result still runs through loop with i==length-1 (initially) through i==0, with only functional difference being that the `while()` version ends with i== -1 after the loop (if it lives on), instead of i==0.

Comment: @TOOGAM (int i=length; i--; ) works in C/C++ because 0 evaluates as false, but not all languages have that equivalence.  I guess you could say i-- > 0.

Comment: Naturally, if using a language that requires " `> 0` " to get desired functionality, then such characters should be used because they are required by that language.  Still, even in those cases, using just the " `> 0` " is simpler than doing the two-part process of *first* subtracting one, and then *also* using " `>= 0` ".  Once I learned that through a bit of experience, I got into the habit of needing to use the equal sign (e.g., " `>= 0` ") in my loop test conditions far less frequently, and resulting code has generally felt simpler since.

Comment: @BryceWagner if you need to do `i-- > 0`, why not try out the classic joke, `i --> 0`!

Comment: @porglezomp Ah, yes, [the *goes to* operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/486504). Most C-like languages, including C, C++, Java and C#, has that one.

Comment: This is actually the most practical answer. The testing answers do not provide a way to simply write a correct loop on the first try. I tend to plug in values to the loop iteration variables, not so much to the boundary expressions.

Answer (score 12):

[Off-by-one errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) are one of the most common programming mistakes. Even experienced developers get this wrong sometimes. Higher level languages usually have iteration constructs like `foreach` or `map` which avoids explicit indexing altogether. But sometimes you do need explicit indexing, as in your example.

The challenge is how to think of *ranges* of array cells. Without a clear mental model, it becomes confusing when to include or exclude the end points.

When describing array ranges, the convention is to **include lower bound, exclude upper bound**. For example the range 0..3 is the cells 0,1,2. This conventions is used throughout 0-indexed languages, for example the `slice(start, end)` method in JavaScript returns the subarray starting with index `start` up to *but not including* index `end`.

It is clearer when you think about range indexes as describing the edges *between* array cells. The below illustration is an array of length 9, and the numbers below the cells is aligned to the edges, and is what is used to describe array segments. E.g. it is clear from the illustration than the range 2..5 is the cells 2,3,4.

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 6 │ 7 │ 8 │   -- cell indexes, e.g array[3]
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   -- segment bounds, e.g. slice(2,5) 
        └───────────┘ 
          range 2..5
```

This model is consistent with having array length be the upper bound of an array. An array with length 5 have cells 0..5, which means there are the five cells 0,1,2,3,4. This also means the length of a segment is the higher bound minus the lower bound, i.e. the segment 2..5 has 5-2 = 3 cells.

Having this model in mind when iterating either upwards or downwards makes it a lot clearer when to include or exclude the end points. When iterating upwards you need to include the start point but exclude the end point. When iterating  downwards you need to exclude the start point (the higher bound) but include the end point (the lower bound).

Since you are iterating downwards in your code, you need to include the low bound, 0, so you iterate while `j >= 0`.

Given this, your choice to have the `rightIndex` argument represent the last index in the subarray breaks the convention. It means you have to include both endpoints (0 and rightIndex) in the iteration. It also makes it difficult to represent the empty segment (which you need when you are starting the sort). You actually have to use -1 as rightIndex when inserting the first value. This seem pretty unnatural. It seem more natural to have `rightIndex` indicate the index after the segment, so 0 represent the empty segment.

Of course your code is extra confusing because it expands the sorted subarray with one, overwriting the item immediately after the initially sorted subarray. So you read from index j but writes the value to j+1. Here you should just be clear that j is the position in the initial subarray, before the insertion. When index operations gets too tricky it helps me to diagram it on a piece of grid paper.

Comment: Can you please show or elaborate more on the last para?

Comment: @CodeYogi: I would draw a small array as a grid on a piece of paper, and then step through an iteration of the loop manually with a pencil. This helps me clarify what actually happens, e.g that a range of cells is shifted right, and where the new value is inserted.

Comment: *"there are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors."*

Comment: @CodeYogi: Added a small diagram to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: Great insight specially you last two pars are worth reading, the confusion is also due to the nature of the for loop, even I find the right index the loop decrements j one time before termination and hence gets me one step back.

Comment: Very. Excellent. Answer. And I'd add that this inclusive/exclusive index convention is also motivated by the value of `myArray.Length` or `myList.Count` - which is always one more than the zero-based "rightmost" index. ... The length of the explanation belies the practical and simple application of these explicit coding heuristics. The TL;DR crowd is missing out.

Comment: Excellent indeed.  However one must keep in mind that these conventions are just that, convensions.  I have (though rarely I must admit) seen some locally grown scripting languages where these conventions will not apply.  Nothing will replace testing the code once written.

Comment: Re: Inclusive, exclusive, I try to keep the math / C++ model in mind [begin, end) where arras[end] is not / can not be  referenced. Thus the array[1..n] is really [1..n+1), which most Algolish languages use for for loops ( when the test is <, which I nearly always use rather than <=).

Answer (score 11):

> I got too frustrated because of the lack of correct computing model in my head.

Is a very interesting point to this question and it generated this comment:-

> There is only one way: understand your problem better. But that is as general as your question is. – *Thomas Junk*

...and Thomas is right.  Not having a clear intent for a function should be a red-flag - a clear indication that you should immediately STOP, grab a pencil and paper, step away from the IDE, and break the problem down properly; or at very least sanity-check what you have done.

I've seen so many functions and classes that have become a complete mess because the authors have attempted to define the implementation before they have fully defined the problem.  And it's so easy to deal with.

If you don't fully understand the problem then you're also unlikely to be coding the optimal solution (either in terms of efficiency or clarity), nor are you going to be able to create genuinely useful unit tests in a TDD methodology.

Take your code here as an example, it contains a number of potential flaws which you've not considered yet for example:-

- what if rightIndex is too low?  (clue: it *will* involve data loss)
- what if rightIndex is outside the array bounds? (will you get an exception, or did you just create yourself a buffer overflow?)

There are a few other issues related to the performance and design of the code...

- will this code need to scale?  Is keeping the array sorted the best option, or should you look at other options (like a linked-list?)
- can you be sure of your assumptions?  (can you guarantee the array be sorted, and what if it isn't?)
- are you reinventing the wheel?  Sorted arrays are a well-known problem, have you studied the existing solutions?  Is there a solution already available in your language (such as `SortedList<t>` in C#)?
- should you be manually copying one array entry at a time?  or does your language provide common functions like JScript's `Array.Insert(...)`? would this code be clearer?

There are plenty of ways this code could be improved but until you have properly defined what you need this code to do, you're not developing code, you're just hacking it together in the hope that it will work.  Invest the time in it and your life will get easier.

Comment: Even if you're passing your indexes to an existing function (such as Array.Copy), it can still require thought to get bound conditions correct.  Imagining what happens in a 0 length and 1 length and 2 length situations can be the best way to make sure you're not copying too few or too many.

Comment: @BryceWagner - Absolutely true, but without a clear idea of what problem is that you're actually solving you're going to spend a lot of time thrashing about in the dark in a 'hit and hope' strategy which is by far the OP's biggest problem at this point.

Comment: I have already broken my problem into sub-problem. Actually the procedure mentioned above is not the original problem but a **private** helper function for `InsertionSort` hence I need no bound checking for that.

Comment: I think you mean `System.arraycopy`, not `Arrays.copyOfRange`. The code is for an in-place sort, but `copyOfRange` creates a new array.

Comment: @Jules - the point was to illustrate that the languages offer ways to do what we need them to and it makes sense to investigate them rather than reinventing the wheel but I do take your point.  In fact `arraycopy` would probably not be great either as we'd want to copy part of an array into itself which could have some fun consequences depending on the implementation, but that would be heading to chat territory.

Comment: @CodeYogi - you have and as pointed out by others you have broken the problem into sub-problems rather poorly, which is why a number of answers mention your approach to solving the problem as the way to avoid it.  It's not something you should take personally, just experience from those of us who have been there.

Comment: @JamesSnell I would be more then happy to see real examples now, show me the code. Let me know how to write a good quality testable insertion sort. No matter if its already implemented in some book. Telling something bad is not going to help others but showing it how to do may change the view point.

Comment: @CodeYogi, I think you may have confused this site with Stack Overflow.  This site is the equivalent of a Q&A session *at a whiteboard*, not at a computer terminal.  "Show me the code" is a pretty explicit indication that you are on the wrong site.

Comment: @Wildcard +1: "Show me the code" is, to me, an excellent indicator as to why this answer is right and that maybe I need to work on ways to better demonstrate that it's a human-factor / design problem that can only be addressed by changes in the human process - no amount of code could teach it.

Answer (score 5):

The introduction to your question makes me think you haven't learned to code properly.  Anyone who is programming in an imperative language for more than a few weeks should really be getting their loop bounds right first-time in more than 90% of cases.  Perhaps you are rushing to start coding before you've thought through the problem sufficiently.

I suggest you correct this deficiency by (re-)learning how to write loops -- and I'd recommend a few hours working through a range of loops with paper and pencil.  Take an afternoon off to do this.  Then spend 45 min or so a day working on the topic until you really get it.

It's all very well testing, but you should be testing in the expectation that you generally get your loop bounds (and the rest of your code) right.

Comment: I wouldn't be so assertive about the skills of OP. Making boundary mistakes is easy, especially in a stressful context such as a hiring interview. An experienced developer could do those mistakes as well, but, obviously, an experienced developer would avoid such mistakes in the first place through testing.

Comment: @MainMa - I think while Mark could have been more sensitive, I think he's right - There's interview stress and there's just hacking code together without due consideration to defining the problem.  The way the question is worded points very strongly to the latter and that is something that can best be solved in the long term by making sure you have a solid foundation, not by hacking away at the IDE

Comment: @JamesSnell I think you are getting over confident about yourself. Look at the code and tell me what makes you think that its under documented? If you see clearly there is nowhere mentioned that I couldn't solve the problem? I just wanted to know how to avoid repeating same mistake. I think you get all your program correct in one go.

Comment: @CodeYogi If you're having to do 'trial and error' and you're 'getting frustrated' and 'making the same mistakes' with your coding then those are signs that you didn't understand your problem well enough before you began writing.  Nobody's saying you didn't understand it, but that your code could have been better thought out and they're signs that you're struggling which you have the choice to pick up on and learn from, or not.

Comment: @CodeYogi ...and since you ask, I rarely get my looping and branching wrong because I make a point of having a clear understanding of what I need to achieve before I write code, it's not hard to do on something simple like a sorted array class.  As a programmer one of the hardest things to do is concede that you are the problem, but until you do that you won't start writing really good code.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I should put some flesh on my comment:

> There is only one way: understand your problem better. But that is as general as your question is

Your point is

> Although I got my assumptions correct after some trial and error but I got too frustrated because of the lack of correct computing model in my head.

When I read `trial and error`, my alarm bells start ringing. Of course many of us know the state of mind, when one wants to fix a small problem and has wrapped his head around other things and starts guessing in one or the other way, to make the code `seem` to do, what is supposed to do. Some hackish solutions come out of this - and some of them are pure *genius*; but to be honest: *most of them are not*. Me included, knowing this state.

Independendly from your concrete problem, you asked questions, about how to improve:

## 1) Test

That was said by others and I would have nothing valuable to add

## 2) Problem Analysis

It is hard to give some advice to that. There are only two hints I could give you, which probably help you improving your skills on that topic:

- the obvious and most trivial one is in the long term the most effective: solve many problems. While practicing and repeating you develop the mindset which helps you for future tasks. Programming is like any other activity to be improved by hard work practicing

Code Katas are a way, which might help a bit.

> How do you get to be a great musician? It helps to know the theory, and to understand the mechanics of your instrument. It helps to have talent. But ultimately, greatness comes from practicing; applying the theory over and over again, using feedback to get better every time.

[Code Kata](http://codekata.com/)

One site, which I like very much: [Code Wars](http://www.codewars.com/)

> Achieve mastery through challenge
>   Improve your skills by training with others on real code challenges

They are relatively small problems, which help you sharpen your programming skills. And what I like most on *Code Wars* is, that you could compare *your* solution to one of *others*.

Or maybe, you should have a look at [Exercism.io](http://exercism.io/) where you get feedback from the community.

- The other advice is nearly as trivial: *Learn to break down problems*
  You have to train yourself, breaking down problems into really small problems.
  If you say, you have problems in *writing loops*, you make the mistake, that you see the loop as a whole construct and do not deconstruct it into pieces. If you learn to take things apart *step by step*, you learn to avoid such mistakes.

I know - as I said above sometimes you are in such a state - that it is hard to break "simple" things into more "dead simple" tasks; but it helps a lot.

I remember, when I first learned *professionally* programming, I had *huge* problems with debugging my code. What was the problem? *Hybris* - The error can not be in such and such region of the code, because I *know* that it can not be.
And in consequence? **I skimmed through code instead of analyzing it**
I had to learn - even if it was tedious to break my code down *instruction for instruction*.

## 3) Develop a Toolbelt

Besides knowing your language and your tools - I know these are the shiny things of which developers think first - **learn Algorithms** (aka reading).

Here are two books to start with:

- [Introduction into algortihms](http://www.amazon.de/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262531968)
- [Algorithms](http://www.amazon.de/Algorithms-Robert-Sedgewick-ebook/dp/B004P8J1NA/ref=sr_1_1?s=books-intl-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1460906813&sr=1-1&keywords=algorithms%20sedgewick)

This is like learning some recipes to start off cooking. At first you don't know what to do, so you have to look, what prior *chefs* cooked for you. The same goes for algortihms. Algorithms are like cooking recipies for common meals (data structures, sorting, hashing etc.) If you know them (at least try to) by heart, you have a good starting point.

## 3a) Know programming constructs

This point is a derivative - so to say.
Know your language - and better: *know, what constructs are possible* in your language.

A common point for bad or inefficent code is sometimes, that the programmer does not know the difference between different types of loops (`for-`, `while-` and `do`-loops). They are somehow all interchangeably useable; but in some circumstances choosing another looping construct leads to more elegant code.

And there is [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) ...

P.S.:

> otherwise your comment is no good than Donal Trump.

## Yes, we should make coding great again!

A new motto for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Ah, let me tell you one thing very seriously. I have been doing everything you mentioned and I can even give you my link on those sites. But the thing that is getting frustrating for me is instead of getting the answer of my question I am getting every possible advice on programming. Just one guy has mentioned `pre-post` conditions till now and I appreciate it.

Comment: From what you say, it is difficult to imagine where your problem is.  Perhaps a metaphor helps: for me it is like saying "how can I see" - the obvious answer for me is "use your eyes"  because seeing is so natural for me, I can not imagine, how one can not see. The same goes for your question.

Comment: Agree completely with alarm bells on "trial and error."  I think the best way to fully learn the problem solving mindset is to run algorithms and code with paper and pencil.

Comment: Um...why do you have a non-sequitur grammatically poor jab at a political candidate quoted without context in the middle of your answer about programming?

Answer (score 2):

Getting this right *easily* and *fluently* is a matter of experience.  Even though the language doesn't let you express it directly, or you're using a more complex case than the simple built-in thing can handle, what you *think* is a higher level like "visit each element once in revere order" and the more experienced coder translates that into the right details instantly because he's done it so many times.

Even then, in more complex cases it's easy to get wrong, because the thing you're writing is typically *not* the canned common thing. With more modern languages and libraries, you *don't* write the easy thing because there is a canned construct or call for that. In C++ the modern mantra is "use algorithms rather than writing code".

So, the way to make sure it's right, for this kind of thing in particular, is to look at the **boundary conditions**.  Trace through the code in your head for the few cases on the edges of where things change. If the `index == array-max`, what happens? What about `max-1`? If the code makes a wrong turn it will be at one of these boundaries.  Some loops need to worry about the first or last element as well as the looping construct getting the bounds right; e.g. if you refer to `a[I]` and `a[I-1]` what happens when `I` is the minimal value?

Also, look at cases where the number of (correct) iterations is extreme: if the bounds are meeting and you will have 0 iterations, will that just work without a special case? And what about just 1 iteration, where the lowest bound is also the highest bound at the same time?

Examining the edge cases (both sides of each edge) is what you should do when writing the loop, and what you should do in code reviews.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem correctly, your question is how to think to get loops right from the first try, not how to make sure your loop is right (for which the answer would be testing as explained in other answers).

What I consider a good approach is to write the first iteration without any loop. After you've done this, you should notice what it should be changed between iterations.

Is it a number, like a 0 or an 1? Then you most likely need a for, and bingo, you also have your starting i. Then think how many times you want to run the same thing, and you'll also have your end condition.

If you don't know EXACTLY how many times it will run, then you don't need a for, but a while or a do while.

Technically, any loop can be translated to any other loop, but the code is easier to read if you use the right loop, so here are some tips:

1. If you find yourself writing a if(){...;break;} inside a for, you need a while and you already have the condition
2. "While" is maybe the most used loop in any language, but it shouldn't imo. If you find yourself writing bool ok=True; while(check){ do something and hopefully change ok at some point}; then you don't need a while, but a do while, because it means that you have everything you need to run the first iteration.

Now a bit of context... When I first learned to program (Pascal), I didn't speak English. For me, "for" and "while", didn't make much sense, but the "repeat" (do while in C) keyword is almost the same in my mother tongue, so I would use it for everything. In my opinion, repeat (do while) is the most natural loop, because almost always you want something to be done and then you want it to be done again, and again, until a goal is reached. "For" is just a shortcut that gives you an iterator and weirdly places the condition at the beginning of the code, even though, almost always, you want something to be done until something happens. Also, while is just a shortcut for if(){do while()}. Shortcuts are nice for later, but the easiest way to get the loops right from the first try is to write them in the same way as your brain is thinking, which is "repeat(do) {something} until(while) (you have to stop)" and then use the appropriate shortcut if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to give a more detailed example of how to use pre/post conditions and invariants to develop a correct loop. Together such assertions are called a specification or contract.

I am not suggesting that you try to do this for every loop. But I hope that you will find it useful to see the thought process involved.

In order to do so, I will translate your method into a [tool called Microsoft Dafny](http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Xgplh), which is designed to prove the correctness of such specifications. It also checks termination of each loop. **Please note that Dafny does not have a `for` loop so I have had to use a `while` loop instead.**

Finally I will show how you can use such specifications to design an, arguably, slightly simpler version of your loop. This simpler loop version does infact have the loop condition `j > 0` and the assignment `array[j] = value` - as was your initial intuition.

*Dafny will prove for us that both of these loops are correct* and do the same thing.

I will then make a general claim, based on my experience, about how to write correct backwards loop, that will perhaps help you if faced with this situation in the future.

**Part One - Writing a specification for the method**

The first challenge we are faced with is determining what the method is actually supposed to do. To this end I designed pre and post conditions which specify the behaviour of the method. To make the specification more exact I have enhanced the method to make it return the index where `value` was inserted.

```
method insert(arr:array<int>, rightIndex:int, value:int) returns (index:int)
  // the method will modify the array
  modifies arr
  // the array will not be null
  requires arr != null
  // the right index is within the bounds of the array
  // but not the last item
  requires 0 <= rightIndex < arr.Length - 1
  // value will be inserted into the array at index
  ensures arr[index] == value 
  // index is within the bounds of the array
  ensures 0 <= index <= rightIndex + 1
  // the array to the left of index is not modified
  ensures arr[..index] == old(arr[..index])
  // the array to the right of index, up to right index is
  // shifted to the right by one place
  ensures arr[index+1..rightIndex+2] == old(arr[index..rightIndex+1])
  // the array to the right of rightIndex+1 is not modified
  ensures arr[rightIndex+2..] == old(arr[rightIndex+2..])
```

This specification fully captures the behaviour of the method. My main observation about this specification is that it would be simplified if the procedure was passed the value `rightIndex+1` rather than `rightIndex`. But since I cannot see where this method is called from I do not know what effect that change would have on the rest of the program.

**Part Two - determining a loop invariant**

Now we have a specification for the behaviour of the method, we have to add a specification of the loop behaviour that will convince Dafny that executing the loop will terminate and will result in the desired final state of `array`.

The following is your original loop, translated into Dafny syntax with loop invariants added. I have also changed it to return the index where value was inserted.

```
{
    // take a copy of the initial array, so we can refer to it later
    // ghost variables do not affect program execution, they are just
    // for specification
    ghost var initialArr := arr[..];


    var j := rightIndex;
    while(j >= 0 && arr[j] > value)
       // the loop always decreases j, so it will terminate
       decreases j
       // j remains within the loop index off-by-one
       invariant -1 <= j < arr.Length
       // the right side of the array is not modified
       invariant arr[rightIndex+2..] == initialArr[rightIndex+2..]
       // the part of the array looked at by the loop so far is
       // shifted by one place to the right
       invariant arr[j+2..rightIndex+2] == initialArr[j+1..rightIndex+1]
       // the part of the array not looked at yet is not modified
       invariant arr[..j+1] == initialArr[..j+1] 
    {
        arr[j + 1] := arr[j];
        j := j-1;
    }   
    arr[j + 1] := value;
    return j+1; // return the position of the insert
}
```

This verifies in Dafny. You can see it yourself by [following this link](http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Xgplh). So your loop does correctly implement the method specification that I wrote in part one. You will need to decide if this method specification is really the behaviour that you wanted.

Note that Dafny is producing a proof of correctness here. This is a far stronger guarantee of correctness than can possibly be obtained by testing.

**Part Three - a simpler loop**

Now that we have a method specification that captures the behaviour of the loop. We can safely modify the implementation of the loop while still retaining confidence that we have not changed the loop behaviour.

I have modified the loop so that it matches your original intuitions about the loop condition and final value of `j`. I would argue that this loop is simpler than the loop you described in your question. It is more often able to use `j` rather than `j+1`.

1. Start j at `rightIndex+1`
2. Change the loop condition to `j > 0 && arr[j-1] > value`
3. Change the assignment to `arr[j] := value`
4. Decrement the loop counter at the end of the loop rather than the begining

Here is the code. Note that the loop invariants are also somewhat easier to write now:

```
method insert2(arr:array<int>, rightIndex:int, value:int) returns (index:int)
  modifies arr
  requires arr != null
  requires 0 <= rightIndex < arr.Length - 1
  ensures 0 <= index <= rightIndex + 1
  ensures arr[..index] == old(arr[..index])
  ensures arr[index] == value 
  ensures arr[index+1..rightIndex+2] == old(arr[index..rightIndex+1])
  ensures arr[rightIndex+2..] == old(arr[rightIndex+2..])
{
    ghost var initialArr := arr[..];
    var j := rightIndex+1;
    while(j > 0 && arr[j-1] > value)
       decreases j
       invariant 0 <= j <= arr.Length
       invariant arr[rightIndex+2..] == initialArr[rightIndex+2..]
       invariant arr[j+1..rightIndex+2] == initialArr[j..rightIndex+1]
       invariant arr[..j] == initialArr[..j] 
    {
        j := j-1;
        arr[j + 1] := arr[j];
    }   
    arr[j] := value;
    return j;
}
```

**Part Four - advice about backward looping**

After having written and proved correct many loops over quite a few years, I have the following general advice about looping backwards.

*It is almost always easier to think about and write a backward (decrementing) loop if the decrement is performed at the beginning of the loop rather than the end.*

Unfortunately the `for` loop construct in many languages makes this difficult.

I suspect (but cannot prove) that this complexity is what caused the difference in your intuition about what the loop should be and what it actually needed to be. You are used to thinking about forward (incrementing) loops. When you want to write a backward (decrementing) loop you try to create the loop by trying to reverse the order that things happen in a forward (incrementing) loop. But because of the way the `for` construct works you neglected to reverse the order of the assignment and loop variable update - which is needed for a true reversal of the order of operations between a backward and forward loop.

**Part Five - bonus**

Just for completeness, here is the code you get if you pass `rightIndex+1` to the method rather than `rightIndex`. This changes eliminates all the `+2` offsets that are otherwise required to think about the correctness of the loop.

```
method insert3(arr:array<int>, rightIndex:int, value:int) returns (index:int)
  modifies arr
  requires arr != null
  requires 1 <= rightIndex < arr.Length 
  ensures 0 <= index <= rightIndex
  ensures arr[..index] == old(arr[..index])
  ensures arr[index] == value 
  ensures arr[index+1..rightIndex+1] == old(arr[index..rightIndex])
  ensures arr[rightIndex+1..] == old(arr[rightIndex+1..])
{
    ghost var initialArr := arr[..];
    var j := rightIndex;
    while(j > 0 && arr[j-1] > value)
       decreases j
       invariant 0 <= j <= arr.Length
       invariant arr[rightIndex+1..] == initialArr[rightIndex+1..]
       invariant arr[j+1..rightIndex+1] == initialArr[j..rightIndex]
       invariant arr[..j] == initialArr[..j] 
    {
        j := j-1;
        arr[j + 1] := arr[j];
    }   
    arr[j] := value;
    return j;
}
```

Comment: Would really appreciate a comment if you downvote

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to stay clear of the topics mentioned galore already.

> What are tools/mental models to avoid such mistakes?

**Tools**

For me, the biggest tool to write better `for` and `while` loops is not to write any `for` or `while` loops at all.

Most modern languages try to target this problem in some fashion or other. For example, Java, while having `Iterator` right from the start, which used to be a bit clunky to use, introduced short-cut syntax to use them easier in a latler release. C# has them as well, etc.

My currently favoured language, Ruby, has taken on the functional approach (`.each`, `.map` etc.) full-front. This is *very* powerful. I just did a quick count in some Ruby code-base I'm working on: in about 10.000 lines of code, there are zero `for` and about 5 `while`.

If I were forced to pick a new language, looking for functional/data based loops like that would be very high on the priority list.

**Mental models**

Keep in mind that `while` is the barest minimum of abstraction you can get, just one step above `goto`. In my opinion, `for` makes it even worse instead of better since it chunks all three parts of the loop tightly together.

So, if I am in an evironment where `for` is used, then I make damn sure that all 3 parts are dead simple and always the same. This means I will write

```
limit = ...;
for (idx = 0; idx < limit; idx++) {
```

But nothing very more complex. Maybe, maybe I'll have a countdown sometimes, but I will do my best to avoid it.

If using `while`, I stay clear of convoluted inner shenannigans involving the loop condition. The test inside the `while(...)` will be as simple as possible, and I will avoid `break` as best I can. Also the loop will be short (counting lines of code) and any larger amounts of code will be factored out.

Especially if the actual while condition is complex, I will use a "condition-variable" which isvery easy to spot, and not place the condition into the `while` statement itself:

```
repeat = true;
while (repeat) {
   repeat = false; 
   ...
   if (complex stuff...) {
      repeat = true;
      ... other complex stuff ...
   }
}
```

(Or something like that, in the correct measure, of course.)

This gives you a very easy mental model which is "this variable is running from 0 to 10 monotonously" or "this loop runs until that variable is false/true". Most brains seem to be able to handle this level of abstraction just fine.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse loops, in particular, can be difficult to reason about because many of our programming languages are biased toward forward iteration, both in the common for-loop syntax and by the use of zero-based half-open intervals.  I'm not saying that it's wrong that the languages to made those choices; I'm just saying that those choices complicate thinking about reverse loops.

In general, remember that a for-loop is just syntactic sugar built around a while loop:

```
// pseudo-code!
for (init; cond; step) { body; }
```

is equivalent to:

```
// pseudo-code!
init;
while (cond) {
  body;
  step;
}
```

(possibly with an extra layer of scope to keep variables declared in the init step local to the loop).

This is fine for many kinds of loops, but having the step come last is awkward when you're walking backwards.  When working backwards, I find it's easier to start the loop index with the value *after* the one I want and to move the `step` portion to the top of the loop, like this:

```
auto i = v.size();  // init
while (i > 0) {  // simpler condition because i is one after
    --i;  // step before the body
    body;  // in body, i means what you'd expect
}
```

or, as a for loop:

```
for (i = v.size(); i > 0; ) {
    --i;  // step
    body;
}
```

This can seem unnerving, since the step expression is in the body rather than the header.  That's an unfortunate side effect of the inherent forward-bias in for loop syntax.  Because of this, some will argue that you instead do this:

```
for (i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    body;
}
```

But that's a disaster if your index variable is an unsigned type (as it might be in C or C++).

With this in mind, let's write your insertion function.

1. Since we'll be working backward, we'll let the loop index be the entry after the "current" array slot.  I would design the function to take the *size* of the integer rather than an index to the last element because half-open ranges are the natural way to represent ranges in most programming languages and because it gives us a way to represent an empty array without resorting to a magic value like -1.

   ```
   function insert(array, size, value) {
     var j = size;
   ```
2. While the new value is smaller than the *previous* element, keep shifting.  Of course, the previous element can be checked only if there *is* a previous element, so we first have to check that we're not at the very beginning:

   ```
     while (j != 0 && value < array[j - 1]) {
       --j;  // now j become current
       array[j + 1] = array[j];
     }
   ```
3. This leaves `j` right where we want the new value.

   ```
     array[j] = value; 
   };
   ```

*Programming Pearls* by Jon Bentley gives a very clear explanation of insertion sort (and other algorithms), which can help build your mental models for these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply confused about what a `for` loop actually does and the mechanics of how it works?

```
for(initialization; condition; increment*)
{
    body
}
```

1. First, the initialization is executed
2. Then the condition is checked
3. If the condition is true, the body is run once.  If not goto #6
4. The increment code is executed
5. Goto #2
6. End of loop

It might be useful for you to rewrite this code using a different construct.  Here's the same using a while loop:

```
initialization
while(condition)
{
    body
    increment
}
```

Here are some other suggestions:

- Can you use another language construct like a foreach loop?  This takes care of the condition and increment step for you.
- Can you use a Map or Filter function?  Some languages have functions with these names that internally loop through a collection for you.  You just supply the collection and the body.
- You should really spend more time familiarizing yourself with `for` loops.  You'll use them all the time.  I suggest that you step through a for loop in a debugger to see how it executes.

* Note that while I use the term "increment", it's just some code that's after the body and before the condition check.  It can be a decrement or nothing at all.

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

## Attempt of additional insight

For **non-trivial algorithms** with loops, you could try the following method:

1. **Create a fixed array** with 4 positions, and put some values in, **to simulate** the problem;
2. Write your algorithm to **solve the given problem**, **without any loop** and **with hard-coded indexings**;
3. After that, **substitute hard-coded indexings** in your code with some variable `i` or `j`, and increment/decrement these variables as necessary (but still without any loop);
4. **Rewrite your code, and put the repetitive blocks inside a loop**, fulfilling the pre and post conditions;
5. [*optional*] rewrite your loop to be in the form you want (for/while/do while);
6. **The most important is to write your algorithm correctly; after that, you refactor and optmize your code/loops if necessary** (but this might make the code non-trivial anymore for a reader)

**Your problem**

```
//TODO: Insert the given value in proper position in the sorted subarray
function insert(array, rightIndex, value) { ... };
```

**Write the body of the loop manually multiple times**

Let's use a fixed array with 4 positions and try to write the algorithm manually, without loops:

```
           //0 1 2 3
var array = [2,5,9,1]; //array sorted from index 0 to 2
var leftIndex = 0;
var rightIndex = 2;
var value = array[3]; //placing the last value within the array in the proper position

//starting here as 2 == rightIndex

if (array[2] > value) {
    array[3] = array[2];
} else {
    array[3] = value;
    return; //found proper position, no need to proceed;
}

if (array[1] > value) {
    array[2] = array[1];
} else {
    array[2] = value;
    return; //found proper position, no need to proceed;
}

if (array[0] > value) {
    array[1] = array[0];
} else {
    array[1] = value;
    return; //found proper position, no need to proceed;
}

array[0] = value; //achieved beginning of the array

//stopping here because there 0 == leftIndex
```

**Rewrite, removing hard-coded values**

```
//consider going from 2 to 0, going from "rightIndex" to "leftIndex"

var i = rightIndex //starting here as 2 == rightIndex

if (array[i] > value) {
    array[i+1] = array[i];
} else {
    array[i+1] = value;
    return; //found proper position, no need to proceed;
}

i--;
if (i < leftIndex) {
    array[i+1] = value; //achieved beginning of the array
    return;
}

if (array[i] > value) {
    array[i+1] = array[i];
} else {
    array[i+1] = value;
    return; //found proper position, no need to proceed;
}

i--;
if (i < leftIndex) {
    array[i+1] = value; //achieved beginning of the array
    return;
}

if (array[i] > value) {
    array[i+1] = array[i];
} else {
    array[i+1] = value;
    return; //found proper position, no need to proceed;
}

i--;
if (i < leftIndex) {
    array[i+1] = value; //achieved beginning of the array
    return;
}

//stopping here because there 0 == leftIndex
```

**Translate to a loop**

With `while`:

```
var i = rightIndex; //starting in rightIndex

while (true) {
    if (array[i] > value) { //refactor: this can go in the while clause
        array[i+1] = array[i];
    } else {
        array[i+1] = value;
        break; //found proper position, no need to proceed;
    }

    i--;
    if (i < leftIndex) { //refactor: this can go (inverted) in the while clause
        array[i+1] = value; //achieved beginning of the array
        break;
    }
}
```

**Refactor/rewrite/optimize the loop the way you want:**

With `while`:

```
var i = rightIndex; //starting in rightIndex

while ((array[i] > value) && (i >= leftIndex)) {
    array[i+1] = array[i];
    i--;
}

array[i+1] = value; //found proper position, or achieved beginning of the array
```

with `for`:

```
for (var i = rightIndex; (array[i] > value) && (i >= leftIndex); i--) {
    array[i+1] = array[i];
}

array[i+1] = value; //found proper position, or achieved beginning of the array
```

**PS:** code assumes input is valid, and that array does not contain repetitions;

Answer (score -1):

This is why I would avoid writing loops that operate on raw indices, in favor of more abstracted operations, whenever possible.

In this case, I would do something like this (in pseudo code):

```
array = array[:(rightIndex - 1)] + value + array[rightIndex:]
```

Answer (score -3):

In your example, the body of the loop is quite obvious. And it is quite obvious that some element has to be changed at the very end. So you write the code, but without the start of the loop, the end condition, and the final assignment.

Then you go away from the code and find out which is the first move that needs to be performed. You change the start of the loop so that the first move is correct. You go away from the code again and find out which is the last move that needs to be performed. You change the end condition so that the last move will be correct. And finally, you go away from your code and figure out what the final assignment must be, and fix the code accordingly.

Comment: Can you please put up some example?

Comment: The OP had an example.

Comment: What do you mean? I am the OP.